# Problem understanding the proof of a limit

Tags: limits, proof-verification

We claim that the limit of the sequence $d_n$ =
$2n+4\over 5n+2$ is $2\over
5$
. Proof: Given $\alpha > 0$, let
N =
$1\over
5$*($16\over 5\alpha$-2)

. Then for all n ≥ N, we have n ≥$1\over
5$*($16\over 5\alpha$-2) implying that $5n+2$≥$16\over 5\alpha$..

How did he get to this formula? 
N =
$1\over
5$*($16\over 5\alpha$-2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $\alpha >0$, let $N =$ _____ (to be filled in later). Then whenever $n>N$,

$$\left\lvert \frac{2n+4}{5n+2} - \frac{2}{5}\right\rvert = \left\lvert\frac{10n + 20-10n-4}{25n + 10}\right\rvert = \left\lvert\frac{16}{25n+10}\right\rvert < \left\lvert \frac{16}{25N+10}\right\rvert = \frac{16}{25N+10}.$$

You would like

$$\frac{16}{25N+10} = \alpha$$

to complete the proof. So now solve for $N$ by

$$\frac{16}{\alpha} = 25N+10 \implies \frac{16}{25\alpha} - \frac{10}{25} = N \implies N = \frac{1}{5} \left(\frac{16}{5\alpha} - 2\right).$$

Then go back and fill in the blank.

Answer (score 0):

No, just take $a_n = |d_n - \frac{2}{5}| = \frac{16}{|5 (5n +2)|}$. Clearly you can make this fraction arbitrarily small. So choose some small $\varepsilon$, e.g. 0.01 and show for what $n \geq n_0 \ a_n$ is within $\varepsilon-$radius of $0$.